# split string and add to new row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a list df that looks like this:

```
>df
gene_id GO
LOC_Os02g43120.1    GO:0008270 GO:0005515
LOC_Os12g21850.1    GO:0003700 GO:0006355 GO:0005515 GO:0034645 GO:0043565
LOC_Os06g30330.1    GO:0005488
LOC_Os07g37690.1    GO:0016758 GO:0008152
```

Im not sure how to put it in the right word but i would like all the gene_ids with more than one GO to be separated into a different row.

Expected output:

```
GO:0008270  LOC_Os02g43120.1
GO:0005515  LOC_Os02g43120.1
GO:0003700  LOC_Os12g21850.1
GO:0006355  LOC_Os12g21850.1
GO:0005515  LOC_Os12g21850.1
GO:0034645  LOC_Os12g21850.1
GO:0043565  LOC_Os12g21850.1
GO:0005488  LOC_Os06g30330.1
GO:0016758  LOC_Os07g37690.1
GO:0008152  LOC_Os07g37690.1
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using chained operations [.split()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), [.assign()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html), [.explode()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

Data:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "gene_id": ["LOC_Os02g43120.1", "LOC_Os12g21850.1", "LOC_Os06g30330.1", "LOC_Os07g37690.1"],
    "GO": ["GO:0008270 GO:0005515", "GO:0003700 GO:0006355 GO:0005515 GO:0034645 GO:0043565", "GO:0005488",
           "GO:0016758 GO:0008152"]
}
```

Code:

```
df = (pd
      .DataFrame(data=data)
      .assign(GO=lambda x: x.GO.str.split(pat=" "))
      .explode(column="GO")
      .reset_index(drop=True)
      )

print(df)
```

Output:

```
            gene_id          GO
0  LOC_Os02g43120.1  GO:0008270
1  LOC_Os02g43120.1  GO:0005515
2  LOC_Os12g21850.1  GO:0003700
3  LOC_Os12g21850.1  GO:0006355
4  LOC_Os12g21850.1  GO:0005515
5  LOC_Os12g21850.1  GO:0034645
6  LOC_Os12g21850.1  GO:0043565
7  LOC_Os06g30330.1  GO:0005488
8  LOC_Os07g37690.1  GO:0016758
9  LOC_Os07g37690.1  GO:0008152
```

Comment: `df.assign(GO=df['GO'].str.split()).explode('GO', ignore_index=True)[df.columns[::-1]]`

Comment: good call on ignore_index=True saves a .reset_index()